# How to return value as an integer

Tags: python-3.x, blynk

This code print value as:

```
['38']

['25']

['57']

['61']

['73']
```

etc... How do I make it return value as an integer?

Like this:

```
38

25

57

61

73
```

```
import BlynkLib

# Initialize Blynk
blynk = BlynkLib.Blynk('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

# Register Virtual Pins
@blynk.VIRTUAL_WRITE(1)
def my_write_handler(value):
    #print('Current V1 value: {}'.format(value))

    print(value)

while True:
    blynk.run()
```

Thanks

Comment: I see `blynk` for first time, but I would call `print(*value)` to print values inside the list.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute

> ```
>     print(value)
> ```

you see e.g.

> ['38']

You can pick out `'38'` by taking the zero-th element, using `value[0]`.

Then, to convert it from string to integer, call int: `int(value[0])`.

If you might possibly get an empty list, then add a guard:

```
    if len(value) > 0:
        num = int(value[0])
```

Consider using tuple unpack:

```
    num, *_ = map(int, value)
```

---

Since you're apparently receiving a list of multiple values,
it would be clearer to use the identifier `values` as the formal parameter
of your handler callback function.